# Spacing and aligning text

Tags: html, css

I want to add space between the two columns

and align skills__subtitle, skills__text somewhat center to the page and not center to the second column for 756px above screen

here is my code

```css
    .row {
        display: flex;
      }
    
    .column {
        flex: 50%;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="skills__container bd-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the width of your column to 48% and add `justify-content:space-between` to your row will add the space.

```css
    .row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-between;

      }
    
    .column {
        flex: 48%;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="skills__container bd-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```

I don't really understand the second part of your question, mind clarifying it?

Answer (score 0):

try this i know your issue butt you give margin to your column-box
Rather your column okay ..

```css
    .row {
        display: flex;
      }
    
    .column-box {
       
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="skills__container bd-grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
     <class="column-box">
         <h2>Column 1</h2>
         <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <class="column-box">
          <h3>Column 2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>
```